# angular2 dependency injection - multiple layer - components need to know too much

Tags: angular2-services

I've read most/all of the SO angular2 DI questions and gotten closer to my goal but not quite.

I'd like there to be a single instance of SvgA (shared across components), but each service to have their own instance of a sub service (SubSvc).

I think I understand a lot of the DI: if I declare SvcA at the top level then all components will share a single instance, but if I declare it in the 'providers' for ComponentOne the it will get its own instance of SvcA.

I've found two solutions but they both have downsides - I wonder if I'm missing another solution.

### Solution 1

## index.ts

```
import {SvcA} from 'svc_a';
import {SvcB} from 'svc_b';
export const APP_PROVIDERS = [ SvcA, SvcB ];
```

## componentOne.ts

```
(no providers set)
constructor( http: Http, svca: svcA ) {}
```

## svc_a.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SvcA {
constructor(http:Http) {
    subsvc = new SubSvc(http); // this works - but doesn't use DI for SubSvc
    subsvc.configure( stuff )
```

## sub_svc.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SubSvc {
    private http: Http;
    constructor( http: Http ) {}
```

### Solution 2

## componentOne.ts

```
providers: [SvcA, SubSvc]
constructor( http: Http, svca: SvcA ) {}
```

## svc_a.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SvcA {
constructor(http: Http, @Inject(SubSvc) subSvc: SubSvc) {
subsvc.configure( stuff )
```

The first solution doesn't use DI for the subsvc, which I don't like.

The second solution uses DI but requires that ComponentOne know something about SubSvc, even if it doesn't use it directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design flaw (a leaky abstraction) of Angular 2. You can's inject a subservice into a service without defining a provider for the subservice outside.  Even when you inject an Http into your SvcA you have to specified its provider in the external componentOne.  In this regard the injection of SubSvc into SvcA is no different than injecting Http into SvcA.

I don't know of any elegant solution.

I opened this issue at Angular's GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622

Comment: Indeed. I also find it unfortunate that your issue, after sparking serious discussion, was closed arbitrarily. Frankly the entire framework leaks implementation details to an insane degree. The lack of this feature doesn't just make maintenance hard it makes it arbitrary and confusing. Something breaks and you have to fix it incrementally by discovering how it was implemented knowing there was no intuition or pattern you could have followed to avoid said breakage.